# Input adds text to element on page

Tags: html, input

```
<input type="text" id="example"></input>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Is there anyway I can make text entered in `#example` appear in `#test`?

Comment: This is only possible using javascript, are there restrictions on using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Javascript. Basically, with jQuery:

```
$("#example").change(function(){

    $("#test").html($("#test").html() + $("#example").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick:

```
$('#example').keyup(function(){
    $('#test').val(this.value);
});
```